# Can’t get HTTPD to start due to server port configuration issue

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

My `httpd.conf` shows it's listening on port 80.  I think I am supposed to change the IP to IP of my machine, but I am not sure and wisely hesitant.

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

However my virtual hosting is showing a port 443, how do I change this? Is this the root of my problem?

*Update*

'VirtualHost *default*:443' = /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

This tells me Virtual Hosting is correct. I feel like I can eliminate all information that relates to 443 from this scenario to get to the answer.

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:<VirtualHost _default_:443>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:#ServerName www.example.com:443
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.rpmnew:Listen 443 https
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.rpmnew:<VirtualHost _default_:443>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.rpmnew:#ServerName www.example.com:443
```

which is

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I am trying to learn from [a similar thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781534/apache2-server-not-starting). I'm on Fedora so its a bit different for me to understand.

`systemctl status httpd.service` says:

```
httpd[1182]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 18 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
```

Line 18 says | Listen 80

```
httpd[1182]: Cannot define multiple Listeners on the same IP:port

systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

line 18 of /etc/httpd/conf.d.ssl.conf | `Listen 80`

This is where I get confused because `grep  '443' /etc/httpd/conf.d/*`
shows my `ssl.conf` file as 443 but when I reading the `httpd.conf` file I see here the `12.34.56.78:80` is a preventative IP. Therefore I should add my machines IP here and to listen on 80 and 443.

Comment: So what does the command `systemctl status httpd.service` say? Please [edit] your post and include these details.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to indicate you may have multiple `Listen` directives in your Apache configuration file(s) specifying the same IP/port 80 combination.

`Listen` (as a general rule) should only appear once in `httpd.conf` (e.g. as `Listen 80`) and once in your default SSL configuration (e.g. as `Listen 443`).

And while it is possible to have multiple `Listen` directives on the same port (e.g. 80), they all must have different IP:port combinations.

> Therefore I should add my machine's IP here and `Listen` on 80 and 443.

Apache [Listen](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html) directives can take two general forms: "Per IP" and "Global" (all available IPs):

```
# Per IP
# Listen 12.34.56.78:80

# Global (i.e includes ex. 12.34.56.78)
Listen 80
```

The configuration above works. Something like the following will generally work as well (assuming your system has mutiple IPs):

```
# Per IP
Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 23.56.78.90:80

# Global (i.e includes ex. 12.34.56.78)
# Listen 80
```

This will likely not work (i.e. Apache will fail to start):

```
# Per IP
Listen 12.34.56.78:80

# Global (i.e includes ex. 12.34.56.78)
Listen 80
```